# Adding an if idle for x seconds condition in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, loops, timer

I have a loop with an on/ff toggle that checks for some conditions, if those conditions are met the loop begins until the toggle is turned off. I would like to add another condition that checks if the user is idle for 200 ms, if this condition is met the loop starts/continues running otherwise it stops/doesn't continue. Is there a way to do this? By idle I mean no mouse movement or keyboard key presses.

Basically something like this:

```
if (a.IsValid && b.Percent > 0 && b.Percent < StringToInt(PercentTextBox.Text) && ***IDLE FOR 200 MS***)
```

I'm using visual studio.

Comment: xaml, using microsoft visual studio

Comment: Try using [GetLastInputInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo). You'll have to do a PInvoke to do it. The link also contains an example that does exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the mouse move and key down events of your form to check for activity. Set a flag to true if there is activity and use a timer to check duration.

Form level variables:

```
bool idle = true;
int duration = 0;
```

Mouse move and key up events:

```
idle = false
```

Fire a timer tick event every 1 ms:

```
duration++;
If (duration >= 200 & idle = true)
{
    idle = true;
}
```